# How to get values from json response and on corresponding value pass the corresponding index ios

Tags: ios, arrays, json

I am new to ios. I am getting response from json like...i want to pass data to json by passing the id of selected pro which i select from picker view. i dont know how to pass the selected id with their selected pro. Means when i send the pro.. i also get their id of that selected pro.Anyone can plz help me out for this.

```
pro =     (
                {
            id = 2;
            pro = abcd;
        },
                {
            id = 3;
            pro = ab;
        },
              {
            id = 45;
            pro = Mango;
        }
    );
    status = 1;
```

// getting dictinary data

```
if (responseData != nil)
    {

        jsonDict = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        NSMutableDictionary *proDict = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"pro"];

       NSLog(@"MY DATA $$$$ %@",proDict);

        NSMutableDictionary *proDict2 = [proDict valueForKey:@"pro"];
        NSLog(@"My second Pro %%%% %@",proDict2);

        proArray = [proDict2 valueForKey:@"pro"];

        idOfPro = [proDict2 valueForKey:@"id"];

 //   
        idOfPro = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"pro"];



        NSLog(@"My pro array %@",idOfPro[0]);

        NSMutableDictionary *itemDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        for (NSDictionary *proItemDict in idOfPro)
        {
            [itemDict setObject:proItemDict forKey:proItemDict[@"pro"]];
            NSLog(@"My dictionary of selected index value %@",proItemDict);

        }

      }
// Response data i get 
caseStatus =     {
        Claimcase = 25;
        completeBad = 0;
        completecase = 0;
        feedbackAwating = 0;
        openDelcase = 4;
        status = 1;
    };
    pro =     {
        pro =         (
                        {
                id = 2;
                pro = abcd;
            },
                        {
                id = 3;
                pro = ab;
            },//// so on......
   }
        );
        status = 1;
    };
    reminder =     {
        msg = "No reminder for today";
        status = 0;
    };
    type = dashboard;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy and there are different ways to do it.I pick the easy one and share the logic as follows.
1.The json result has two values i.e: pro and status.
2.Pro is an array of dictionaries.
i.e: `

```
NSArray *proArr=[jsonResDict objectForKey:@"pro"];
proArr[0]=   {
            id = 2;
            pro = abcd;
        }
proArr[1]={
            id = 3;
            pro = ab;
        }
`
```

and it goes on..

3.To get the pro value and its id is the key part and you just need to iterate the loop with the proArr.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *itemDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];  
 for(NSDictionary *proItemDict in proArr)
     {
       [itemDict setObject:proItemDict forKey:proItemDict[@"pro"]];
//storing the entire dictionary with item name and id for the name key.
//name is what you will be getting from picker.And you can easily get the id by taking the relative item from dictionary whose key matches to the name
    }
```